# jHipster client running on tomcat is not communicating with server which is running in dev mode mvnw

Tags: java, tomcat, jhipster, tomcat8, yarnpkg

there I've generated my jHipster client and server separately and build the client with **yarn run build** command for production and deployed the **www** folder in **tomcat** which is running on port 8989 and my server is running with ./mvnw on localhost:8080. The issue is my client is not communicating with the server and I've requested my server through postman it successfully communicates to the server.

Am I doing something wrong? I'm new to jHipster please guide me. I'm unable to identify the issue.

**JHipster  4.7.0**  , **Tomcat 8**

Comment: Tomcat starts the www folder correctly but app does not send request to server

Comment: Now I've upgraded the jHipster as suggested by [@Gael marizou]  and downloaded a new client but still, it's not communicating with the server. here are some logs from tomcat 127.0.0.1 - - **[29/Sep/2017:18:55:27 +0500] "POST /www/oauth/token HTTP/1.1" 404 1024** ............................why it is still using www even I've set SERVER_API_URL: "http://localhost:8080/"

Answer (score 0):

JHipster angular code expects the API to be served by same server as the javascript app. For you it's not the case as they are on different ports.

So, 2 alternatives:

- edit the javascript to change the base URL of API (see `SERVER_API_URL` in `webpack/webpack.common.js` that writes to `app.constants.ts`) but you need to upgrade to JHipster 4.9.0
- use a reverse proxy in front of your 2 servers (similar to what JHipster does with webpack that serves client code and proxifies API calls to java spring boot app).

Comment: Thank you for replying @Gael Marziou for the first option as I have separate client and server, I've tested from different machines, one as the client and second as the server by changing the SERVER_API_URL it works fine for yarn start (running client in dev mode). I'll try updating the project to JHipster 4.9.0, to run my client in tomcat.

Comment: I've upgraded the jhipster and downloaded a new client but still it's not communicating with the server.  here are some logs from tomcat 127.0.0.1 - - [29/Sep/2017:18:55:27 +0500] "POST **/www/oauth/token** HTTP/1.1" 404 1024                                              why it is still using **www** even i've set SERVER_API_URL: `"http://localhost:8080/"`  @Gael marizou

Comment: What do you mean by "downloaded a new client"? Anyway it just means that the SERVER_API_URL may not be used for this call, search for it in typescript code fix it and then consider submitting a pull request.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I've found the issue and fixed it, now submitting the pull request although I've never submitted the pull request before.

Comment: **auth-oauth2.service.ts** was missing SERVER_API_URL constant in post request at line  32. As I've never submitted a pull request, it's complicated for me, if someone can commit the change it would be great. What I did was **1) generate jHipster client using --> yo jhipster:client --auth=oauth2** and updated the auth-oauth2.service.ts file at line 32